# I need to find the logic error in my tp - pseudocode

Tags: loops, printing, pseudocode

At school, I have a Pseudocode problem. I need to print every number from 0 to 99, and when the number can be divided by 3, it needs to also type "Boo" beside the number. If it can be divided by 5, it needs to "type" Phew beside that number, e.g.

```
2

3 Boo

4

5 Phew

6 Boo
```

---

They are asking it in pseudocode. Here's what I tried to do, but my teacher says the logic is not good enough:

```
int i = 0;

WHILE i < 100 DO    

 print i to screen
   IF i%3 = 0 THEN
     Print " Boo" to screen
   ELSE IF i%5 = 0 THEN
     print " Phew"  to screen
   END IF
   Switch lines on screen
   i = i+ 1

END WHILE
```

Does anyone know how I could fix this?

Comment: What is a "tp"?

Answer (score 0):

May not work as there are different "styles" of pseudocode:

```
int i = 0;

WHILE i < 100 DO:
   print i

   IF int(i % 3) == true THEN:
      three == true

   ELSE:
      three == false

   IF int(i % 5) == true THEN:
      five == true

   ELSE:
      five == false

   IF three == true AND five == false THEN:
     print i, " Boo"

   ELIF five == true AND three == false THEN:
     print i, " Phew"

   ELIF five == true AND three == true ​THEN:
    ​print i, ,"Boo", " Phew"

   ELIF five == false AND three == false ​THEN:
    ​print i

   ENDIF

   i = i + 1

ENDWHILE
```